# cordova/phonegap 2.0 iOS

Tags: ios, cordova-2.0.0

I get deprecation warnings for invokeString in Main and App .m files.  I haven't seen any posts on how to fix this.  So far it's working ok, just curious.

```
self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;   <-'invokeString' is depcrecated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CB-853] Deprecate window.invokeString - use window.handleOpenURL(url) instead

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-commits/201207.mbox/%3C20120716205424.998B414A2D@tyr.zones.apache.org%3E

Comment: I found that but what do I replace that line with?  Or do I just remove all references to invokeString.

Comment: I just commented that line, seems fine.

Comment: Same here, I commented invokeString related stuff and it seems to work. But still not sure if it's the correct thing to do...

Comment: You are safe. Look inside MainViewController.m line 111

Answer (score 8):

This really helped cause I couldn't figure out how much to comment out... drove me crazy.

http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/phonegap-2-1-0-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8-from-download-to-ios-app-store/

In `MainViewController.m` comment out:

```
/* #pragma UIWebDelegate implementation
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*) theWebView
{
    ... all ...
} */
```

and in `AppDelegate.m` comment out:

```
// self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;
```