# PhoneGap 2.0 iOS getting started guide buggy?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I followed the instructions in the PhoneGap 2.0.0 getting started with iOS guide. It seems not update to date, because some files in the created project have other names than in the guide. Apart from this, a warning and error occures while building.

> 1. Warning: Check dependencies: Missing dependency target "CordovaLib (from CordovaLib.xcodeproj)"
> 2. Error: CpResource /VERSION /<...>/Test.app/VERSION
>      cd /<...>/test-phonegap
>      setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>      builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip
>      /VERSION /<...>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.app
>
> error: /VERSION: No such file or directory

Do you have any ideas how get it working? Thanks and best regards.

--
Guide: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Comment: You might want to start over again and make sure you follow all the steps. I've just run the getting started and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I've got the same behavior. But it worked 2 times. My 3rd project is generating that error. I'm interested in the solution !!

Comment: Everyday a Martian people will die when there is no correct answer being accepted in this question.

Comment: the documentation for phonegap is pathetic... confusing terminologies, instructions are terrible as well...

Answer (score 15):

After downloading and decompressing PhoneGap 2.0.0, open "phonegap-phonegap-ff91e6e/lib/ios/Cordova-2.0.0.dmg" and then install the "Cordova-2.0.0.pkg". Close and re-open your project. It should work.

Comment: This will help solve the fatal error, but he will have 3 warnings after saying 'invokeString' is deprecated.

Comment: i have those warnings too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616614/cordova-phonegap-2-0-ios

Comment: Fixed it. I needed to restart XCode indeed.

Comment: this did not fix the problem for me

Comment: same here, this didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 11):

You need to manually set the CORDOVALIB setting:

Open XCode -> Preferences, go to Locations -> Source Trees

If you don't have a CORDOVALIB entry there, create one:

Click "+" at the bottom, enter:

- Setting Name: CORDOVALIB
- Display Name: CORDOVALIB
- Path: /Users/[your_user_name]/Documents/CordovaLib

The "Path" should point to the folder created by the Cordova Installer (Cordova-2.0.0.pkg).

Comment: +1 this worked for me and the others failed. cleaning isn't going to do much if your project doesn't know where to find the cordovalib directory (mine was in ~/Documents). this may have happened to me because i installed the cordova dmg a step late. who knows... just surprised at how many steps this process takes and how easy it is to mess up, phonegap should reconsider this way of doing things in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

found Solution for me : The CordovaLib.xcodeproj is imported in to the workspace of your project.
If you've got 2 open PhoneGap projects open at the same time, the CordovaLib will only be available for one of the two... close all phonegap projects and open only one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I just cleaned the project and it worked: Product -> Clean

Answer (score 0):

I found that I am using Mountain Lion and had this same issue. I had to go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > "Allow applications downloaded from"

... and then check the option for "Anywhere".  They lock down outside apps to only load from the Mac App Store by default.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging and dropping CordovaLib.xcodeproj (in my Documents/CordovaLib directory - the installer did that part, at least...) into my project (creating it as a subproject) got rid of these errors for me.